# I'm trying to get sum of column in SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sum, android-sqlite

i want to get sum of column price but it show -2 in total price

```
//Dbhandler
 public Cursor gettotalp()
{
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =database.rawQuery("select sum(totalprice) as total from " + TABLE_Users + ";", null);
   Log.d(TAG, "gettotalp: "+cursor.getCount());
    return cursor;
}
//showallsaleitemActivity
 Cursor cursor = db.gettotalp();
    int m=0;
       /* while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            m += cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("totalprice"));
        }*/
    for(int k = 0; k<=cursor.getCount();k++) {
        m += (int) Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cursor.getColumnIndex("totalprice")));
    }
    int i=m;
        tp.setText("" + m);
```

[database table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jeb7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The column that returns the sum in your query is not `totalprice`.
You aliased it as `total`.
To get it, use this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.gettotalp();
cursor.moveToFirst()
int m = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("total"));
```

or, since the query returns only 1 column:

```
int m = cursor.getInt(0);
```

You don't need the `for` loop, which in your code adds twice `-1` and returns `-2` because  `cursor.getColumnIndex("totalprice")` returns `-1` (since the column does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue is that the column name in the cursor does not match the column name passed to the `getColumnIndex` method.

Secondly the value you want is stored in the column of the Cursor, it is not the value of the index of the column in the Cursor. As it is the first and only column the index will be 0 and not the sum of the totalprice column. Instead you need to get the value stored in the column based upon the index of the column using one of the Cursor `get????` methods in this case you want to use either `getInt` or `getString` *(if you want to use the value for calculations then `getInt` means that you don't have to do the parseInt from a String, if you only want to display the value then `getString` could be used)*.

- I personally prefer to get the value using the get method more appropriate to the type of value being retrieved. Hence as it's an integer value then I have used `getInt` even though it's being used as a string.

I would suggest the following 2 snippets of code be used :-

```
// DBHanlder
public int gettotalp() {
    int rv = 0;
    String total_column = "total_price";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =database.rawQuery("select sum(totalprice) as " + total_column  + " from " + TABLE_Users + ";", null);
    Log.d(TAG, "gettotalp: "+cursor.getCount());
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(total_column));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- chances of mistakes reduced by using a variable for the column name alias.
- The Cursor `moveToFirst` method will move to the first row in the Cursor.

  - When a Cursor is returned from the SQLiteDatabase methods that create a Cursor the Cursor is at a position that is BEFORE the first row, so a move is required.
  - All the Cursor `move????` methods return false if the move cannot be made.
- A Cursor should always be closed when it is done with. Not doing so can lead to errors who's underlying cause (such as file handles exhausted) is difficult to determine.

2nd Snippet :-

```
//showallsaleitemActivity
tp.setText(Integer.toString(gettotalp()));
```

**Note**

Instead of using

```
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(total_column))
```

As you are only returning a single value you could use

```
cursor.getInt(0)
```

then the column name is then irrelevant (if valid for the SQL). Personally I prefer to not use hard coded index unless necessary or overly complex to not use them.